# Finding third side of triangle using law of cosine. python

Tags: python, trigonometry, triangle

For some reason the answer I get in the program is 7.091341682475861
It is supposed to be 6.66634. Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong. The equation is fairly simple and straightforward?

```
import math as mt
 def third_side(a, b, c):
                return mt.sqrt((a * a) +
                       (b * b) - 2 * a * b * mt.cos(c))
            c = 37
            a, b = 8, 11
            print(third_side(a,b,c))
```

Comment: This code has several `IndentationError`s. Please [edit] your question and fix those errors. We can't be expected to guess which errors are significant and which are typos. The easiest way to add code is to copy it, paste it into your question, then select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K to format it as a code block. This should maintain all indentation.

Comment: What are `a`, `b`, and `c` here? Are they side lengths? Then why are there three if you're supposed to compute the third side? Are they points? Then why are they single values and not pairs or triples? Is one of them an angle? What is `third_side()` supposed to do? Please read [ask].

Comment: Thank You Chris, I have read How to Ask and will implement it next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.cos

`math.cos` takes input in radians. You should do `mt.cos(c/180*mt.pi)`

```
import math as mt
def third_side(a, b, c):
    return mt.sqrt((a * a) + (b * b) - 2 * a * b * mt.cos(c/180*mt.pi))
c = 37
a, b = 8, 11
print(third_side(a,b,c))
```

Comment: Thanks so so much!

Comment: Perhaps better use `math.radians` (just a bit further down on the same page).

Comment: Or does your image indicate that you insist on using math.pi? :-)

Comment: Thank You Kelly